# Intensity of UVA needed to damage skin and cause ageing

Tags: skin, radiation, uv, melanin

Using a UVA/B measuring device, I was able to determine that approximately $\pu{10 μW/cm^2}$ penetrates a window even when not in direct sunlight. For reference, the intensity of direct sunlight without any glass is approximately $\pu{6000 μW/cm^2}$ UVA (this UV component represents ~6% of all solar energy from direct sunlight that reaches the ground on a clear day) and $\pu{50 μW/cm^2}$ of UVA penetrates the double pane glass window in direct sunlight.

If a person were to sit in front of this window most of the day (about 8 hours). Assuming indirect sunlight, is this $\pu{10 μW/cm^2}$ dose hitting their face going to cause significant skin damage over time?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this stack and how we work. Please note that personal medical advice is off-topic here, which this post leans towards (as in we'd need to know your race and other personal information to make an informed answer; so that would be a clear breach of rules). Having said that, I can see a good question here, that isn't medical advice if you depersonalize it.

Comment: @bob1 You're right I hadn't taken into consideration different races would have different skin types and different susceptibility to skin damage. Though an expert in this field should be able to provide generalized thresholds for different skin types. Hopefully...

Comment: I've depersonalized it and added some specifics - like duration of exposure, without which this is unanswerable. If you disagree with the changes feel free to edit some more or revert, but be aware it might get closed for medical advice.